# DataSnapshot getValue() in Firebase returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

One of my routines in my main activity's onCreate() method is to communicate with the Firebase database to do one of three things:
1) If the user is a returning user, update all of their preferences on Firebase stored using SharedPreferences locally.
2) If the user is new and has no data stored on the cloud (they've never downloaded the app), do nothing.
3) If the user is new but has preferences stored under their unique Facebook profile ID, download their preferences and apply them to the SharedPreferences instance.

I must be missing some key, probably basic, piece of insight into how DataSnapshot works, because I can't get my following code to work:

```
    private void initializeFirebase(){
    my_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference my_ref = my_db.getReference();

    Map<String, ?> values = sharedPreferences.getAll();

    if (values.isEmpty()){
        final String id = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();
        my_ref = my_ref.child("userid");
        my_ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals(id)){
                    data = (Map<String, Object>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    else {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : values.entrySet()) {
            my_ref.child("userid").child(Profile.getCurrentProfile().
                    getId()).child(entry.getKey()).setValue(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

data is a global Map variable that is always null after getValue() is executed.

My JSON tree is organized as: root -> users -> userid -> each preference as a child node to the userid node. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Please be more specific.  Are you saying that DataSnapshot itself is null?  Or its getValue() returns null?  What's the symptom of the problem?

Comment: Also, are you sure you mean to use the string "userid" here?  `my_ref.child("userid")`

Comment: Sorry -- getValue returns null. The Map called "data" is always null.

And I believe so.

Answer (score 2):

According to the API docs for [getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getValue()), it can return null:

> The data contained in this snapshot as native types or null if there is no data at this location.

So, the location you're querying has no data.

I'm going to guess that you didn't want to hard code a value of "userid" in your reference.  I bet you mean to use the user's id from the previous line:

```
final String id = Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId();
my_ref = my_ref.child(id);  // id instead of "userid"
```

Comment: You're right! Yikes... I had a feeling it was something dumb lol.

Comment: If you don't mind marking this answer as correct, I'd appreciate it.